# Is it safer to have an airplane inspected twice a year?

Tags: safety

According to the [Nall report](http://www.aopa.org/-/media/Files/AOPA/Home/Pilot-Resources/Safety-and-Proficiency/Accident-Analysis/Nall-Report/Nall_23_R4.pdf) and as voretaq7 explained [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8294/8389), around 11% of fatalities in general aviation are due to mechanical failure and maintenance issues.  Although these numbers are relatively small (about 25 per year) they are a danger that even a very cautious pilot would seem to have little control over.

**So, if annual inspections were performed twice a year, does the data suggest  it would impact these numbers significantly?**  Please include references to studies and their implications.

Comment: This is hypothetical, as we cannot predict if it was safer to have more inspections. Bear in mind though, that the annual inspection is only one of many. GA aircraft in Germany also have 25hrs, 50hrs and 100hrs inspections, which are performed on the engine and sometimes airframe.

Comment: FWIW, there are some differing opinions around this. At least one well-known GA guy [believes that less maintenance would be preferable to more](https://www.savvyaviation.com/wp-content/uploads/articles_eaa/EAA_2011-03_the-waddington-effect.pdf).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no regulation *preventing* a pilot from paying to have the annual inspection performed every six months? Consequently, if in your opinion doing so would reduce your risk, nothing should prevent you from taking such preventative steps, regardless of the regulations, as long as you meet the requirement of performing annual inspections yearly in accordance with the regulations.

Comment: @mins, I believe the Nall Report includes only accidents in the United States.  And while 25 accidents a year is pretty small, it's about 13% of the fatal accidents.  What I was wondering, is what can a GA pilot do, if anything, to mitigate this risk?  And unfortunately Pondlife's link demonstrates that increasing the frequency of maintenance is not likely the solution.

Comment: This question is the subject of a [meta] discussion: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3316/753