# What are the most common cockpit system and instrument failures in small airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-systems

What could one expect to be the most common cockpit system and reliant indicators to fail in a small airplane like a Cessna 172 or Piper Archer? Would gyroscope failures or vacuum pump failures be one?

Edit: This question is different than this one: [What component of an aircraft is most likely to fail?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22114/what-component-of-an-aircraft-is-most-likely-to-fail) because I am not asking about components, I am asking about systems and instruments.

Comment: Re. your edit, what is the difference you see between a "component" and a "system" or "instrument"?

Comment: I have an FAA magazine that I could answer this question with.

Comment: From the duplicate, according to the selected answer it's clear that the gyros and vacuum pump are not particularly failing components. Do you want to know something else that is not in the duplicate? Please clarify your question.